# ¿Cual es el limite de sobre-escritura de una variable en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Buenas estoy trabajando en una función en JavaScript donde manejo una variable de tipo `let`, estoy manejando un ciclo for donde se repite cierta cantidad de veces, la variable que uso se llama `var1` el problema es que después del ciclo 5, mas exactamente en el ciclo 6 la variable no se sobre escribe. El siguiente es el codigo:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= cantidad[0].numero; i++) {
            let id_producto = '';
            let no_pedido = '';
            let estado = '';
            console.log('Cilo: ' + i + ' ---------------')
            let var1 = variables[i];
            console.log(var1.length)
            if (var1.length == 3) {
                for (let j = 0; j < var1.length; j++) {
                    if (j == 0) {
                        id_producto = var1[j];
                    } if (j == 1) {
                        no_pedido = var1[j];
                    } if (j == 2) {
                        estado = var1[j];
                    }
                };
            };
            if (no_pedido != '') {
                console.log('Id_Producto: ' + id_producto + ' | No_Pedido: ' + no_pedido + ' | Estado: ' + estado);
                await pool.query("insert into `registro_pedidos` (`id_Registro_Pedidos`,`producto_id_Producto`,`pedidos_id_Pedidos`,`Cantidad`) values (default, " + id_producto + ", " + id_Pedido[0].id_Pedido + ", " + no_pedido + ")");
            }
        };
```

El valor de entrada es un json:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  '1': [ '1', '2' ],
  '2': [ '2', '4', 'true' ],
  '3': [ '3', '5' ],
  '4': [ '4', '7', 'true' ],
  '5': [ '5', '7' ],
  '12': [ '12', '25', 'true' ],
  '13': [ '13', '30', 'true' ],
  '14': [ '14', '10', 'true' ],
  '15': [ '15', '3', 'true' ],
  '16': [ '16', '', 'true' ],
  '17': [ '17', '2', 'true' ],
  'dom-jqry_length': '25'
}
```

La cosa es que en el ciclo 6 la `var1` no se sobre escribe, por lo cual no puedo validar el primer `if(var1.length == 3)` y todos mis procesos se paran, nunca me había pasado ese tipo de error, pero no se si existe un limite en sobre escribir los datos sobre la misma variable x cantidad de veces. Datos el error mostrado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: el principio tenia la `var1` como un const después lo pase a let, pero aun así persiste el error. Lo que busco es que la `var1` se sobre escriba x cantidad de veces sin problemas.

Comment: Por algún motivo tachaste parte del error?

Comment: No, no hay un limite de veces que podes sobre escribir una variable, tu problema es otro.

Comment: Suena a que variable[5] no existe. En el código no se ven  ni variables ni cantidad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que estás tratando de acceder a un elemento que no existe en tu objeto..estás tratando tu objeto como si fuera un array. Para eso existe el bucle `for...in` en JavaScript:

```
for (let key in variables) {
            let id_producto = '';
            let no_pedido = '';
            let estado = '';
            console.log('Cilo: ' + key + ' ---------------')
            let var1 = variables[key];
            console.log(var1.length)
            if (Array.isArray(var1)) {
              if (var1.length == 3) {
                for (let j = 0; j < var1.length; j++) {
                    if (j == 0) {
                        id_producto = var1[j];
                    } if (j == 1) {
                        no_pedido = var1[j];
                    } if (j == 2) {
                        estado = var1[j];
                    }
                };
            };
            // el resto de tu código aquí
          }
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, solo falta considerar que el último elemento no es un arreglo, sino cadena y podría generar un comportamiento inesperado. Por otra parte, no estaría mal cambiar ese `var key` por `let key` para que la variable solo esté disponible dentro del ciclo.

Comment: Buena observación. Edité la respuesta para mejorarla

Comment: @CamiloGomez Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, tienes toda la razon puesto que trataba mi `var1` como un arreglo para realizar las validaciones, realmente desconocía la creación del for asignando a `let key` el json directamente. Muchas gracias y gracias todos por tomar su tiempo para ayudarme.